# Multiwebsite and multistore magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, multidomain, multi-website

Can someone please shortly describe how to set domains for my magento 2 different stores views and websites, or maybe recommend for me a good  tutorial, 
thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To short answer, I provide already detail explanation links Hope it help you !.

I consider you understand Following terms

- **Multi-store(different Catalog/Brand)**
- **multi-view(different Region/Language/Currency)**
- **Multi-website(different Domains)**

.

[image]

1. **Please follow it firstly official documentation for overall idea how it works**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

2 **Create a storefront and Configure the server to load your storefront**

> if you need to create multiple store(e.g Nike) , store view(US|IN|FR)

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts.html

3. **Setup multi-Website switcher** :

> if you need to change store view **US|UK|France|German|** drop down from
>   single domain.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290073/how-to-setup-magento-2-website-switcher

4. **Setup multi-Website** :

> if you need to setup multi-store for different domain (e.g **domain1.com**,**domain2.com**) manage from single admin.

https://belvg.com/blog/multistore-in-magento-2-0.html